# Get current asp.net core user ID in another project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

In a controller, for example, I can get user ID by this:

```
User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
```

I have registered business logics, which are implemented in another project, in a DI collection:

```
services.AddScoped<ILogic1, Logic1>();
services.AddScoped<ILogic2, Logic2>();
```

The business logics' methods have to know a current user ID. I would not like to send the user ID as a constructor parameter.

What is the best practice to get the user ID in another project?

Comment: You can pass the user ID as an argument to the methods you are calling or let the business logic retrieve the current user ID from the DI container you are using.

Comment: There is no way of accessing user information without being coupled to HttpContext. And from logic separation stand point, adding MVC dependencies to injected business logic if far from acceptable. I suspect your security layer will grow with time (with custom access policies and management). Why not create a separate, injectable security service, that you might use in your business logic services (where needed). Of course, it needs to be present in your constructor.

Comment: @MilanVidakovic, so, to elaborate further, the security service has methods to get user info, should be implemented in the web project. Should it use UserManager to extract user info?

Comment: I don't know what authorization model you're using, but it should be similar for all. I simply "initialize" my injected security service with Identity data extracted from httpcontext in my mvc layer (controller endpoint). The security layer should be very low on the hierarchy tree (below web and business logic), so you wouldn't have any issues accessing and processing security rules when needed. Edit: Security service should be a separate project, not implemented in the web layer. Otherwise you might run into hierarchy trouble, as the Web layer should always be "above" all other layers.